# Best Way to Display HTML Files in Bulk SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am looking for possible solutions to display HTML files in SharePoint Online sites. I know you can use the embed web part to display static pages. However, is there a better way or is there a way to do it that isn't manual?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy [Modern Script Editor web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to your site and then copy the HTML code to it.
[image]